# Decrypt from Base64 format (Swift)

Tags: swift, base64

Here is Encrypted string using Base64 ->

```
(ew0KICAiTmV3c0dyYXBoIjogWw0KICAgIHsNCiAgICAgICJEYXRlIjogIjA0LUZlYiIsDQogICAgICAiTmV3c1Njb3JlIjogNTAuMCwNCiAgICAgICJUYWJsZU5hbWUiOiAiTmV3c0dyYXBoIg0KICAgIH0sDQogICAge)
```

and Here is the extension method to Decrypt the string

```
extension String
{
    func fromBase64() -> String 
    {
        let data = NSData.init(base64Encoded: self, options: []) ?? NSData()
        return String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
    }
}
```

There is no output in my Text View, but you will get decrypted output for the same string on -> https://www.base64decode.org

But if i took substring from the encrypted string ->

```
ew0KICAiTmV3c0dyYXBoIjogWw0KICAgIHsNCiAgICAgICJEYXRlIjogIjA0LUZlYiIsDQogICAgICAiTmV3c1Njb3JlIjogNTAuMCwNCiAgICAgICJUYWJsZU5hbWUiOiAiTmV3c0dyYXBoIg0KICAgIH0sDQog
```

then my code returns decrypted string.
What is the issue?
can any one please

Comment: `(` and `)` aren't valid Base64 characters

Comment: Also there's no need to use `NSData`'s initialiser as you're just converting to `Data` afterwards – just use `Data`'s initialiser. Also you don't need to include the `options:` parameter if you're not going to pass any options. Also also you can just say `encoding: .utf8` in `String`'s initialiser.

Comment: The number of characters in a valid base64 string needs to be a multiple of 4, but your first string (with removing enclosing parentheses) has 165 characters, that's why `NSData.init(base64Encoded:options:)` cannot decode it. See [RFC-4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648).

Comment: First is ->Than how it is decrypted on  https://www.base64decode.org/. Second is -> I have too much long encrypted string(the above is just a single line from original) form Api call so how to handle it

Comment: 1. Base64 is not encryption, it is an encoding. 2. The length is incorrect ignoring the enclosing parenthesis.

Comment: _how it is decrypted on base64decode.org_ Ask to the author of the site. _how to handle it_ Cut your encoded string at the right 4-character boundaries. (You may need to fix your server side. Usually 64 or 76.) Then you can decode each of them with `Data.init`. But each decoded Data may not be a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, which `String.init` cannot handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Base64 is not encryption, it is an encoding.
2. The length is incorrect ignoring the enclosing parenthesis, Base64 encoding must be a multiple of 4 characters.

Example:

Deleting the last character to create a valid length.

First decode the Base64 string to Data, then encode to  aUTF-8 string.

```
let base64 = "ew0KICAiTmV3c0dyYXBoIjogWw0KICAgIHsNCiAgICAgICJEYXRlIjogIjA0LUZlYiIsDQogICAgICAiTmV3c1Njb3JlIjogNTAuMCwNCiAgICAgICJUYWJsZU5hbWUiOiAiTmV3c0dyYXBoIg0KICAgIH0sDQogICAg"
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64)!
let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)
print(decodedString!)
```

Result:

```
{
  "NewsGraph": [
    {
      "Date": "04-Feb",
      "NewsScore": 50.0,
      "TableName": "NewsGraph"
    },
```

It would seem that Base64 string in the question is incomplete and has been truncated.

Comment: Thanks Zaph. I got my answer.